# How to Execute Windows Commands Using Java - Change Network Settings

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec

In Java, I want to be able to execute a Windows command.

The command in question is `netsh`. This will enable me to set/reset my IP address.

Note that I do not want to execute a batch file.

Instead of using a batch file, I want to execute such commands directly. Is this possible?

---

**Here is my implemented Solution for Future Reference:**

```
public class JavaRunCommand {
    private static final String CMD = 
        "netsh int ip set address name = \"Local Area Connection\" source = static addr = 192.168.222.3 mask = 255.255.255.0";
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            // Run "netsh" Windows command
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD);

            // Get input streams
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            // Read command standard output
            String s;
            System.out.println("Standard output: ");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // Read command errors
            System.out.println("Standard error: ");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been answered so many times. Just look at stackoverflow suggestions to find some of them

Comment: @SJuan76, My apologies. Could you perhaps link me to some of those questions?

Comment: @mre Just look in the sidebar.

Comment: @Matt Ball, *facepalm*...Thank you.

Comment: *sigh* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processbuilder

Comment: https://www.codepuran.com/java/execute-dos-command-java/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh");
```

See [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) Javadoc.

EDIT: A later answer by leet suggests that this process is now deprecated. However, as per the comment by DJViking, this appears not to be the case: [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-). The method is not deprecated.

Comment: In my environment, I had to prepend the command with "cmd /c" i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c netsh");`

Answer (score 32):

Use `ProcessBuilder`

```
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process=pb.start();
BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

while(inStreamReader.readLine() != null){
    //do something with commandline output.
}
```

Comment: What is the basis for that conclusion? Looking into the javadoc, it is not declared as deprecated.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-

Comment: Updating this: Since this question is used as a reference when flagging duplicates (i.e, we point the duplicates to this page), it would be nice to clarify this answer, that has more upvotes that the accepted answer. Is there a source for this information? If no, maybe it should be removed as a wring answer?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

You can run the command with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command>")` (eg. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tree")`). But, this will only run executables found in path, not commands like `echo`, `del`, ... But only stuff like `tree.com`, `netstat.com`, ... To run regular commands, you will have to put `cmd /c` before the command (eg `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c echo echo")`)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command="netstat";
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("the output stream is "+process.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String s; 
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("The inout stream is " + s);
        }                   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works.

Comment: This reads every other line of the output.
Should be:
    `String s;
    while ((s = reader.readLine() != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

[`Runtime#exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).