# Run exe by java Process, get error code 109

Tags: java, windows, exe

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myexe.exe");

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
       br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(),       "GB2312"));
       String value = null;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
       }
    }finally{
       IOUtils.close(br);
    }
```

Then, the output likes below, not the string I want:

Child: Can't read length for data, error code 109

Comment: Doesn't this all depend on your myexe.exe program?

Comment: Could we get some more information on the exe you're trying to run, and the full error thrown?

Comment: I'd use `ProcessBuilder` and redirect the error IO through the stdout and then try and read the response

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is no wrong with my exe. Running exe in cmd window, gets the right answer. And if use '>' redirect the output to a file in cmd window, the same error will appear.

Comment: Fair enough, then good luck debugging this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  It seems that the problem appears, because of  the output of the exe which is too long. Can `ProcessBuilder` solve it ?

Comment: Read it before you call `p.waitFor` (or read it as a separate thread), something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218892/running-a-java-program-from-another-java-program/15220419#15220419) for example or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452964/how-do-i-execute-dos-commands-in-java/16453653#16453653) example

Comment: *"Child: Can't read length for data, error code 109"* is that related to it's input or it's output?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  output of myexe

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that the problem appears, because of the output of the exe which is too long. Can ProcessBuilder solve it ?

As a general rule of thumb, you should always read the output of `Process` before you call `waitFor` (or use a background `Thread` to read it while you `waitFor`)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PBDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myexe.exe");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process pro = pb.start();
            InputConsumer ic = new InputConsumer(pro.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("...Waiting");
            int exitCode = pro.waitFor();

            ic.join();

            System.out.println("Process exited with " + exitCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("sorry" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class InputConsumer extends Thread {

        private InputStream is;

        public InputConsumer(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int in = -1;
                while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) in);
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

In the past, I've either provided an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to the `InputConsumer`, through which some other party can be notified as new input comes in or otherwised cached the output so I can process it after the process has completed, based on your needs

Comment: Thanks, you are right about`waitfor`.  But the problem of too long output data is not solved.

Comment: Is the exe file based python? Without any ideas of what that exe is does or how it works, that's going to be the best we can do

Comment: You could also try using [`ProcessBuilder#inheritIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) before you start the process

Comment: Thanks again. The exe is based on c++ written by myself. And it runs ok independently. After searching from google, I found my problem was because of [ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), which is related to the limitation of Windows's default setting. So, I will change my implementation of my application.