# How to make a java program wait for external script to complete?

Tags: java, linux

I have run an octave script from Java using

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./ProcessImg");
Process p = pb.start();
```

But after executing these statements, the program isn't waiting for the process to finish and comeback.

How do I make the program wait for it? I want to use the file spit out by that script.

Currently I am running the program twice, so that first time it creates the files and also an exception,the second time the program uses the previously created file.

Comment: `Process#waitFor` - but you'll probably also want to drain the process `OutputStream` as this can stall some process's and stop them from working, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713856/run-exe-by-java-process-get-error-code-109/35714130#35714130)

Comment: What do you mean by drain the process?

Comment: Sorry, it should be "process's".  Basically, you need to read the `InputStream` exposed by `Process`, otherwise it's possible that the process's output stream will get filled and the process may stall (and never end)

Comment: There is absolutely no reason, that this question has an "octave" tag, right?

Comment: Actually the file I was running was octave. Anyway, I removed the tag.

Comment: Why did this question get a -1? Is it not a genuine problem?