# Running/Sending CMD command in Java

Tags: java

I want to get rid of a .bat file in java and have the code post directly to CMD.

I have tried multiple variances of the below but i'm not getting it right.

The .bat file contains the following:

```
CD C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"UiPath Platform"\UIRobot.exe -file C:\ProgramData\UiPath\Projects\DM9\Main.xaml
```

I would like Java to post this directly to CMD instead.

Currently my code looks like:

```
String test = in.readUTF();

         if (test.equals("Start"))
         {
             String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:Unipath\\start.bat"};
             Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         }
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has this to do with Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, removed tag

Comment: What is the problem?  What doesn't work? What is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually specified the problem, but I can run a batch file no problem without the `cmd.exe` argument.  i.e. batch file

```
echo off
echo %1
```

can be run using

```
String[] command = {"test.bat", "HELLO"};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

So I suspect your problem lies either with the `cmd.exe` argument or with the fact that your batch command doesn't seem to be valid

```
CD C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"UiPath Platform"\UIRobot.exe -file C:\ProgramData\UiPath\Projects\DM9\Main.xaml
```

Is this a **C**hange **D**irectory command with three arguments, a filename, a `-file` then another filename.  Have you tested the batch file by itself?

Comment: Hi Ross, i have resolved the issue. The .bat file worked perfectly, because java didn't post the cmd command to command prompt it executed a lot quicker. The designer also added no content to the cmd command so it seemed as though nothing was happening. I had him assign an output on that command and it worked perfect! thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote and accept if it helped @Gordon_Dev

Comment: Hi Ross, i cant up vote due to reputation. I wont forget to when i get there. Few more points to go!!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link for detailed example: [Run Dos commands using JAVA](https://www.codepuran.com/execute-dos-command-java)

Courtesy of @akshay-pethani's answer in below question.
[How do I execute Windows commands in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452964/how-do-i-execute-windows-commands-in-java)