# Use cordova/phonegap from java

Tags: java, android, cordova, cmd

Normaly i use cordova to generate a cordova project with cmd from windows.

I generate it via

```
cordova create hello com.something HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova add android
cordova build
```

Now i would like to generate a cordova project from java.
Something like this:

```
public void generateCordovaProject(String folderName, String packageName, String projectName)
```

How it is possible?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I would like to use a special API to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to found info about executing Windows commands using Java, here is example [How to Execute Windows Commands Using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112259/how-to-execute-windows-commands-using-java-change-network-settings)

Comment: Ok, its a way, but it don´t exist a api or something like that?

Comment: I have not seen that such api exists, but you can also create a project Cordova / PhoneGap using plugin for Eclipse MDS applaud for PhoneGap [link to plugin](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com)