# Runtime.exec Error but works in cmd line

Tags: java, outlook, runtime

I am using the following very simple code to open outlook using the cmd line:

```
Start OUTLOOK.EXE
```

When I type it into the Windows Command Processor it works fine but when I use:

```
Runtime.exec(String[]{"Start ", "OUTLOOK.EXE"});
```

or

```
Runtime.exec("Start OUTLOOK.EXE);
```

or

```
Runtime.exec(String[]{"Start", " ", "OUTLOOK.EXE"});
```

In java it does not work (I get this error: Cannot run program "Start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified) why ? I have read about spaces and runtime but I cannot get it working.

Thanks
Ulrich

---

Ok so with some more googling I got it working:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start OUTLOOK.EXE");
```

That will open it, I hope people find this because I have been searching for some hours trying to figure out how to open a program I do not know the file path to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Execute Windows Commands Using Java - Change Network Settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112259/how-to-execute-windows-commands-using-java-change-network-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "start". Just having outlook.exe is enough.

```
Runtime.exec("OUTLOOK.EXE");
```

Comment: And use ProcessBuilder, not Runtime.exec