# Adding exterinal program windows to java program

Tags: java

I am creating a program that commands a router through scripts.  I would like to add a Windows command line window to the frame/panel so that I can run a ping command from the java program without opening up my own instance of the command line.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20600721/230513).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Execute Windows Commands Using Java - Change Network Settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112259/how-to-execute-windows-commands-using-java-change-network-settings)