# Enabling/Disabling IPv6 Windows Setting in a Java program

Tags: java, windows, configuration, windows-7, ipv6

I need to be able to enable/disable the IPv6 settings on my computer from within a Java program.

Basically, I need to follow these directions to turn IPv6 on and off: [How To Disable IPv6 On Windows 7](http://www.informationweek.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-7-/d/d-id/1099490)

But I need to be able to do that though a Java program.  Is this possible?

I'm running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the tool [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc740203%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), specifically to install IPv6 support:

```
netsh int ipv6 install
```

To remove:

```
netsh int ipv6 uninstall
```

Also documented under [KB2478747](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2478747).

See the question [How to Execute Windows Commands Using Java - Change Network Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7112259/175849) to integrate within a Java application.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh int ipv6 install");
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it required a reboot to take effect.  I can't reboot.  When I manually turn IPv6 on/off by checking/unchecking the IPv6 box in the control panel, I don't have to reboot for the changes to take effect. I'm doing automated testing, "turn it on, make sure something works, turn it off, make sure it still works".  So I don't want reboots in the middle of my test plan.  I need a command line way to do the same thing as checking/unchecking the box in the control panel.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using a utility I downloaded and installed called nvspbind.  With this installed, the calls to turn IPv6 and off are:

nvspbind.exe /e "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6 
nvspbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6