# How to make the clock increment in a fixed place?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a 24 hour clock and I want it to increment seconds, minutes, hours in a fixed place like within the Command Shell this.

> 00:00:03

previous lines are replaced instead of adding lines below like this:

> 00:00:01
> 00:00:02
> 00:00:03

How to make something like this?
Here is my code

```
Clock myClock = new Clock();
       
while(true) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
       
   System.out.println("Enter ticks");
   String ticks = sc.nextLine();
   int input = Integer.parseInt(ticks);
             
   for(int i = 0; i < input ; i++) {            
       System.out.println(myClock.ToTimeFormat());
       myClock.Tick();
       Thread.sleep(100);              
   } 
}
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: 1) I can't really understand what exactly you are asking and 2) you haven't provided the code for your `Clock`, so how are people supposed to help you? What do you mean when you say "_increment in one place_"?

Comment: What I need is that when I run the program I want the clock to count like this 00:00:23 but in my code the clock count like this 00:00:01  00:00:02 and so on

Comment: I don't think the clock class will add something

Comment: java does not support command line funktions as under c - you can only try to clean the screen by using the default windows command (`cls`)... (assuming you are under a windows OS)

Comment: see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112259/how-to-execute-windows-commands-using-java-change-network-settings) for further details

Comment: you could see this thread for another soultion idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001335/java-gotoxyx-y-for-console-applications

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < input ; i++) {            
       System.out.println("\r" + myClock.ToTimeFormat());
       myClock.Tick();
       Thread.sleep(100);              
   }
```

`\r` returns the start of the line, the problem is that it works on some terminals/ and it does not in others.
Try it out.